# Compare values of double in list and have colour depending on value c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of doubles and I want to display a label with the values which is fine. But I want the background to have a shading of red if the value is close to the max or blue if it's close to the min, or white if it's close to the median.

```
    public partial class UserControlTest : Window
    {
    private double Highest;
    private double Minimum;
    private double Median;

    public UserControlTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        Data dataSet = dataSource.GetData();

        Bind(dataSet);
    }

    private void Bind(Data dataSet)
    {
        Highest = Convert.ToDouble(dataSet.Values.Max());
        Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(dataSet.Values.Min());
        Median = ((Highest - Minimum) / 2) + Minimum;
        stk1.Children.Add(DisplayLabel(dataSet));
        stk1.Children.Add(DisplayMax(dataSet));
        stk1.Children.Add(DisplayMin(dataSet));
        stk1.Children.Add(DisplayMed(dataSet));

    }

    private Label DisplayLabel(Data dataSet)
    {
        var label = new Label()
        {
            Content = String.Join(" , ", dataSet.Values),
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue)
        };

        return label;
    }



    private Label DisplayMax(Data dataSet)
    {
        var maxlabel = new Label() 
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
        };
        return maxlabel;
    }

    private Label DisplayMin(Data dataSet)
    {
        var minlabel = new Label()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
        };
        return minlabel;
    }

    private Label DisplayMed(Data dataSet)
    {
        var medlabel = new Label()
        {
            Content = Median,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink)
        };
        return medlabel;
    }



}
```

}

Comment: And your question is? I think with your code, you will write 1 number in 4 way and only one is like you wanted.

Comment: Sorry my question is how to change the background of the label accordingly, for example the max is 28 and the min is 12. The first value in the list is 15 so I want it to have a gradient colour of blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MVVM i see two ways of doing this.

1. create a wrapper list with the double value and the color property. you can simply bind both values in wpf.
2. use a converter for the label background with the double value as input.

Comment: Do I need to do a foreach loop for the values in the list? I'm very new to all this